# Trying to set up a javascript that alerts user when changing price amount in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, jquery, netsuite

I'm trying to use NetSuite suitescript and alert the user when changing the line item price for an item. The user would have to change the price level to "Custom" in order for them to edit the unit price. This is what I currently have but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
//if user is in item price line
if (type == 'item') {
    // var priceLevel = nlapiIsLineItemChanged;
    var priceLevel = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'pricelevel');

    // return error if user tries to change price
    if (priceLevel == 'Custom') {
        alert('You are not allowed to change item price!!!!!');
        return false; // requires user to fix error
    }
}
return true;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I suppose it alerts every time, right? It might be because of this line `if (priceLevel = 'Custom')` You are not comparing here, you are assigning.

Comment: Also, the whole code is poorly formatted and appears to have one extra `}`.

Comment: Your question shows a complete lack of understanding of basic concepts such as how to compare two values.  How much will an answer to this question really help you?

Comment: try nlapiGetCurrentLineItemText and '==' for comparing.

Comment: I edit the op because there are several mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line ..

`var priceLevel = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'pricelevel'));`

.. does not give you `Custom` but the internal id of the `Custom` price level.  If I recall correctly, this will be `-1`.